# How do I preview HTML in real time on my HTML page

Tags: html, preview, live

I'm trying to build a tool that allows you to create a HTML-page using Blockly-Blocks ([Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly)).
It is a HTML-page that looks like this at the moment:

[image]

It can already create code out of blocks, but now I need a way to preview the result live on the page in the upper right corner. Does anyone have an idea how that could be somewhat easily implemented? I've looked around a bit but only found tools that are able to Live-Preview HTML but none to use in your own page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Save the code and open with browser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could document.write the page into an iFrame

This will alas not work here at SO since iFrames are sandboxed

but it does work in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fgtrnq04/)

[image]

PS: Your HTML is malformed.

```js
const ifr = document.preview;
const html = `<!doctype html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Preview</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="font-family:Ariel, sans-serif; background-color: #ffcc00; color: #003300">
      <ol>
        <li>Line 1</li>
        <li>Line 2</li>
      </ol>
    </div>  
    </body>
    </html>`;
ifr.document.write(html);
ifr.document.close();
```

```css
#preview {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<iframe name="preview" id="preview"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! That solved my problem. 
With malformed do you only mean that there are some newlines missing or are there actually syntactic errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the code in a file ex: "index.html"

Copy the code from the right side bottom from

`<DOCTYPE HTML>` to the end `</html>`

And open the file with your browser simple as that :)

Comment: How is that previewing? And then they have to save it all the time. It is an interactive html page.